# 3D walkthroughs

Tags: modeling, animation

Ive seen lots of info on making stunning scenes made with blender but can find very little about 3D walk-through.

Hopefully a simple question, is it possible to do a FPP walk-through in Blender?

To put it in context I'm a landscape designer and the company has be asked to do a walk-through of a long (1-2km), thin (100m) park running through a subdivision. I didn't start learning blender with this in mind, but the project came up and it got me wondering.

Comment: Absolutely  Blender could do this. No problem, however you will need to wrap your head around the 3D world. It gets confusing very fast. I dont know what your time frame is and how realistic it needs to be. It could be done from very cartoonish to completely photo realistic and everything in between. I would start with this beginner series if you have the time. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JYj6e-72RDs&t=867s

Comment: Also after you have modeled everything the way you want, you could even upload your file in 3D and send it to your client so they can "walk" around the park on their own time. Just a thought, so You know stuff like this exist. https://sketchfab.com/models/d919fe879a1741f68f36e46bbba31923

Comment: Thanks for answering, much appreciated. Thats great news. I have actually subscribed to his channel, so its good to know Im on the right track. Ive spent the last 10+ years using CAD so im hoping some skills are transferable, although I realize there is a ton to learn. Exciting times.

Comment: I did not know that. That sounds awesome. Im even more fired up now to learn this program. Thanks again.

Comment: Glad I could help, If you are coming from CAD you should have no problem then. This site is full of talented and helpful people along with https://blenderartists.org/forum/ So if you get stuck just ask here and you should get an answer pretty quick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can move within any scene in blender using [Walk/Fly Mode](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/3dview/navigate/walk_fly.html)

Using a combination of mouse and the <kbd>W</kbd><kbd>A</kbd><kbd>S</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> keys will allow you to move about in the 3D scene interactively, as the player of any first person game.

To create fixed animations you can animate the camera and render it as a video file to be played back later, without the blender interface.