# How do I "look around" in a scene? Also, what's up with zooming?

Tags: navigation

Noob here (be kind). I am coming to Blender because I would like to use it to primarily do Arch Viz renderings and fly through animations. I'm really loving blender so far, but one thing I'm not loving is the navigation in a scene. There are two things about it that are driving me crazy. One is I haven't found a good way to "stand" in an interior space I've modeled and "look around" inside the scene. All of the tutorials I've watch on navigation are super basic. They just cover zooming, panning, and orbiting, which are all fine if you are just needing to navigate around an object. But It gets really cumbersome when you are inside an object, like a room, and need to look all round. This is pretty important for arch viz. SO! does anyone have any tips on this that they can share with me? are there any exhaustive comprehensive navigation tutorials I can look at?
The other thing that I find frustrating with Blender navigation is the zoom seems to be exponential? Like when I use the mouse wheel to zoom in, it gets slower and slower and slower the closer I get to where I'm trying to go to the point that I am never able to actually get there. Is there a better way to zoom that is more linear?
Any tips and tricks from other people doing Arch Viz is greatly appreciated.
Thanks!!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [3D walkthroughs](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/100261/3d-walkthroughs)

Comment: For the zoom question: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/644/why-does-the-zoom-sometimes-stop-at-a-point

Comment: There is a lot of information for beginners already on this site. Use the search box at the top of the page.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure about the zooming, but a cool way to view your model from the inside is to use "Walk Navigation". You can do this by going to "View > Navigation > Walk Navigation", or just press shift-tilda. This allows you to view your scene like a first person shooter game, and it doesn't pan around it. You can also walk around in your scene with WASD, and if you want to be on the ground, you can press Tab to toggle gravity. To exit walk navigation mode, you can either right click to reset the view to what it was, or left click to set that view. This can also be good for deciding a good camera position.

I hope I didn't get too off-topic, these are just tips that might be useful. Hope this helps!

Comment: Fantastic! Thank you. This is exactly what I was looking for.